# Azure App Insights with web test, - ERROR: a single hiding link tag pointing to AI resource is required

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am trying to create a template for App Insights web availability
tests. I am using bicep, and this is my template:

```
param location string = resourceGroup().location


param pingText string = ''


param appInsightsResource string


param tests array

resource tests_0_name 'Microsoft.Insights/webtests@2015-05-01' = {
  name: tests[0].name
  location: location
  tags: {
    'hidden-link:${appInsightsResource}': 'Resource'
  }
  properties: {
    Name: tests[0].name
    Description: tests[0].description
    Enabled: true
    Frequency: tests[0].frequency_secs
    Timeout: tests[0].timeout_secs
    Kind: 'ping'
    Locations: tests[0].locations
    Configuration: {
      WebTest: '<WebTest   Name="${tests[0].name}"   Enabled="True"         CssProjectStructure=""    CssIteration=""  Timeout="120"  WorkItemIds=""         xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010"         Description=""  CredentialUserName=""  CredentialPassword=""         PreAuthenticate="True"  Proxy="default"  StopOnError="False"         RecordedResultFile=""  ResultsLocale="">  <Items>  <Request Method="GET"    Version="1.1"  Url="${tests[0].url}" ThinkTime="0"  Timeout="300" ParseDependentRequests="True"         FollowRedirects="True" RecordResult="True" Cache="False"         ResponseTimeGoal="0"  Encoding="utf-8"  ExpectedHttpStatusCode="${tests[0].expected}"         ExpectedResponseUrl="" ReportingName="" IgnoreHttpStatusCode="False" />        </Items>  <ValidationRules> <ValidationRule  Classname="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.Rules.ValidationRuleFindText, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.WebTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" DisplayName="Find Text"         Description="Verifies the existence of the specified text in the response."         Level="High"  ExecutionOrder="BeforeDependents">  <RuleParameters>        <RuleParameter Name="FindText" Value="${pingText}" />  <RuleParameter Name="IgnoreCase" Value="False" />  <RuleParameter Name="UseRegularExpression" Value="False" />  <RuleParameter Name="PassIfTextFound" Value="True" />  </RuleParameters> </ValidationRule>  </ValidationRules>  </WebTest>'
    }
    SyntheticMonitorId: tests[0].name
  }
}
```

and also a parameters file:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "appInsightsResource": {
      "value": "myappinsight"
    },
    "tests": {
      "value": [
        {
          "name": "5121",
          "url": "http://www.microsoft.com",
          "expected": 200,
          "frequency_secs": 300,
          "timeout_secs": 30,
          "failedLocationCount": 1,
          "description": "a description for test1",
          "guid": "5122",
          "locations": [
            {
              "Id": "us-il-ch1-azr"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "1242",
          "url": "http://www.microsoft.com",
          "expected": 404,
          "frequency_secs": 300,
          "timeout_secs": 30,
          "failedLocationCount": 1,
          "description": "a description for test3",
          "guid": "5211",
          "locations": [
            {
              "Id": "us-il-ch1-azr"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that, when I create this I get an error {"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"BadRequest","message":"A single 'hidden-link' tag pointing to an existing AI component is required. Found none."}]}
"A single 'hidden-link' tag pointing to an existing AI component is required. Found none.
As you can see, I have a tag with hidden link, but Azure points to my tests, which I suppose do not have this tags, I don't know how to add them or what do to to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

The special char `-` was no problem on my side but may be you must ensure that ${appInsightsResource} is the Id and not the name of the AppInsights resource. (That was my mistake)

So me following works:

```
param applicationInsightsName string


resource applicationInsights 'Microsoft.Insights/components@2020-02-02' existing = {
  name: applicationInsightsName  
}

resource symbolicname 'Microsoft.Insights/webtests@2022-06-15' = {
  name: testName
  location: location
  tags: {
    'hidden-link:${applicationInsights.id}': 'Resource'
  }
  kind: 'ping'
  properties: {
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

While adding tags to resources we have some **limitations**. I have noticed that in your Bicep template you are using Special Character `-`.

```json
hidden-link:${appInsightsResource}'
```

Some **Special Characters** are not supported those are `<`, `>`, `%`, `&`, `\`, `?`, `/`,`-`.

#### I have modified your code like below:

```json
resource tests_0_name 'Microsoft.Insights/webtests@2015-05-01' = {
  name: tests[0].name
  location: location
  tags: {
  # While adding tags remove the special charactor
    'hiddenlink:${appInsightsResource}': 'Resource'
  }
```

##### I have tried from my end The result follows:

#### Bicep File

[image]

#### Json Result

[image]

#### Tag added in the Resource

[image]

#### References

- [MS-DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-resources?tabs=bicep#limitations) for Tag Limitation
- [MS-DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-support) for Supported Resources